# Standard deviation of the Hamilton/energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, hamiltonian, superposition

I've been working with a task in QM and I'm not quite sure it makes sense to me. We have a particle in an infinite well in a superposition of two energy-eigenstates, $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$. We first look at $\psi_1$ which consists of a linear combination of three stationary states. We want to find the expectation value of the Hamiltonian (the total energy). I first use the formula

$ \langle H \rangle = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}|c_n|^2E_n$ to find the expectation value for H, and find this to be $\approx 1.2 eV$. Next, the task asks us to find the standard deviation in H, $\sigma_H$. Is it correct then, that we can find $\langle H^2 \rangle$ by $ \langle H^2 \rangle = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}|c_n|^2E_n^2$ ?

Should the standard deviation $\sigma_H$ be zero? In my book, this is shown to be the case when first deriving the Schrödinger equation by the separable solutions method, and it highlights that stationary states are states of definite total energies... so ... I feel it should be zero

Answer (score 1):

That a system is *not* in an eigenstate of an observable, and the dispersion turns out to be zero, should always surprise you and make you suspicious enough to go back to your calculations, to see what you got wrong.

In your case, the reason is confusing $\langle H^{2}\rangle$ with $\langle H\rangle^{2}$.
You will notice that,
$$
\langle H\rangle^{2}\neq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|c_{n}|^{2}E_{n}^{2}
$$
Rather,
$$
\langle H^{2}\rangle=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|c_{n}|^{2}E_{n}^{2}
$$
And then,
$$
\langle H\rangle^{2}=\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|c_{n}|^{2}E_{n}\right)^{2}
$$
Can you take it from there?

Comment: Ooops, my bad! There's a typo in my question, I was actually wanting to ask if $\langle H^2\rangle = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}|c_n|^2E_n^2$. So if this is correct, I find that $\langle H^2\rangle$ = 2.4eV, such that $\sigma_H = 0.98$. Does this make sense?

Comment: Sounds about right. From your numbers I get $\sigma_H=0.96 \textrm{ eV}$. But the dispersion should never be zero, as your system is *not* in an $H$ eigenstate. As long as we agree on *that*...

Comment: I think I've understood, and I do agree! Thanks alot @joigus :)